# how to access these mocks in unittest and pytest

Tags: python, testing

I'm trying to test this function "start_dojot_messenger", which has some objects and methods in it, and I need to test and verify that they were called with those specific parameters.
For example we have messenger.create_channel("dojot.notifications", "r"), and I need to test if it is starting with these parameters.
follow image of the method

```
def start_dojot_messenger(config, persister, dojot_persist_notifications_only):

messenger = Messenger("Persister", config)
messenger.init()
# Persister Only Notification
messenger.create_channel("dojot.notifications", "r")
messenger.on(config.dojot['subjects']['tenancy'],
             "message", persister.handle_new_tenant)
messenger.on("dojot.notifications", "message",
             persister.handle_notification)
LOGGER.info('Listen to notification events')

if str2_bool(dojot_persist_notifications_only) != True:
    LOGGER.info("Listen to devices events")
    # TODO: add notifications to config on dojot-module-python
    messenger.create_channel(config.dojot['subjects']['devices'], "r")
    messenger.create_channel(config.dojot['subjects']['device_data'], "r")
    messenger.on(config.dojot['subjects']['devices'],
                 "message", persister.handle_event_devices)
    messenger.on(config.dojot['subjects']['device_data'],
                 "message", persister.handle_event_data)
```

in my tests I'm doing it that way here.

```
@patch.object(Persister, 'create_indexes')
@patch.object(Config, 'load_defaults')
@patch('history.subscriber.persister.Messenger')
@patch.object(Messenger, 'create_channel', return_value=None)
@patch.object(Messenger, 'on', return_value=None)
def test_persist_only_notifications(mock_create_channel,             mock_on, mock_messenger, mock_config, create_indexes):

from history.subscriber.persister import start_dojot_messenger
from history import conf
p = Persister()
p.create_indexes_for_notifications('admin')

mock_config.dojot = {
    "management": {
        "user": "dojot-management",
        "tenant": "dojot-management"
    },
    "subjects": {
        "tenancy": "dojot.tenancy",
        "devices": "dojot.device-manager.device",
        "device_data": "device-data"
    }
}
# test persist only boolean valued notifications
start_dojot_messenger(mock_config, p, True)

mock_messenger.assert_called()
assert mock_messenger.call_count == 1
```

the first test to check if the Messenger class has been initialized I can do it using the mock: mock_messenger.assert_called()

but the others I can't access.
I figured it could be something like this

mock_messenger.mock_create_channel.assert_called

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I just removed the images, and put the codes